# How can I write independently down either 10Gbe output from a Sonnet Twin 10G Thunderbolt 2 adapter to a network switch?

Tags: networking, mac, raid, switch

I have a job coming up where I need to write at high speeds from an iMac and MacBook Pro to two separate RAID units with the write capability of 1250MB/s (DS3617xsII's w/ 12x 16TB EXOS Enterprise HDD's, RAID Level 5). From the iMac Pro I have a Sonnet Twin10G Thunderbolt 2 Adapter to a Netgear XS712T 12 Port L2 Smart Managed Switch to 2x DS3617xsII's w/ Dual T-Base RJ45 10Gbe Ports. All cables are Cat6a.

From the computer, I'll be reading media independently from a drive at 1200MB/s over a Thunderbolt 3 connection to the iMac. From there I need to write that media to the two separate RAID's both capable of writing at 1200MB/s. My goal is to saturate both 10Gbe connections coming out of the Sonnet Adapter to the Network switch and then to both RAIDs.

My issue is, from my understanding of networking from the computer the ethernet frames sent via the Sonnet 10gbe adapter will be aggregated across the dual output which, from my understanding, will put more strain on the network switch. With the dual input into the switch, my goal would be to assign each input to independently output to one of the RAID's - two separate uninterrupted streams of data.

My current 'safety' solution would be - to utilise the dual I/O on each RAID and have one I/O to the switch and one I/O connected directly to the sonnet dual 10gbe adapter. Forcing it into two separate data streams and other computers can still access the RAID'S if needs be. The Mac wouldn't need to be connected to the network during this period however if necessary I could utilise the integrated 10Gbe I/O port on the Mac itself. However this feels incredibly messy.

Would anyone be able to offer a solution? Write speed is an absolute priority.

Thanks